# SQL - Select statement with extra (unique) where requirement

Tags: sql, oracle

I'm trying to select `id` which has code `I` corresponding to it, but I only want those `id` where `I` is the only corresponding value. The correct `id` would be `5` (`3` and `8` have other `code` values along with `I`). Using Oracle SQL.

```
id code  
4 | G  
4 | O  
5 | I  
3 | G  
3 | I    
8 | G  
8 | I  
8 | O  
9 | G
```

Comment: Please read http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-may-i-not-upload-images-of-code-on-so-when-asking-a-question/285557 and the accepted answer

Comment: My bad, I tried to have it as text, but didn't understand how in the message box it could be achieved. If copied from anywhere(excel, sql developer) it goes as one line. Trying to type using line breaks, then line breaks go together with skipped line, which makes it to take bigger space. Will try again in the future. Thanks!

Comment: If you click on the little "Help" button when editing your question you wind up here: http://stackoverflow.com/help/formatting which explains all options you have to format text

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can do this with aggregation:

```
select id
from t
group by id
having min(code) = 'I' and max(code) = 'I';
```

If `code` can be `NULL`, you need another condition to take that into account.

Comment: `'I'` rather than `5`

Comment: It would be interesting to see what the performance is like on this answer vs. my answer for large datasets.

Comment: @ZacFaragher I can't imagine a scenario where a single scan of the table *(this answer)* would be slower than a self join *(your answer, which requires a scan of T0 and at least an index scan of T1)*.

Comment: @GordonLinoff Thank you! Worked as a charm. I've spent half day playing with group by, didn't even think that you can set min/max on letters.

Comment: @MatBailie looking at the plans in SQL Server for this very limited data set and putting it into a temp table, this solution has an expensive `sort` operation to facilitate the aggregation, but my solution just uses 2 index scans. Mine also has the benefit of being extendable to 2 or more `code` values, while this is limited to just the one.

Comment: @ZacFaragher . . . Add a `select distinct` to your query so the results are comparable.  Your code so it is comparable.

Comment: @GordonLinoff Yep, you're right. If there's multiple `[5, 'I']`s, then mine will return all of them. Yours is more optimal in that case, but the point about extensibility still remains.

Comment: @ZacFaragher . . . This method is quite extensible ( more extensible than yours).  It just requires modifying the `having` clause, particularly using `having sum(case when . . . )`.

Comment: @zacfaragher Check the plans again after putting a covering index on `(id, code)`.

Comment: @MatBailie I did try it with that and it does remove the sort operator, but as OP commented the dataset comes from joins on multiple tables, so you can't necessarily depend on that.

Answer (score 0):

This solution works by left-joining the table onto itself matching on ID but where the Code is different, and finding those records where the join failed.
This will work in most SQLs, it might need some tweaking for your flavor

```
SELECT DISTINCT T0.* FROM [Table] AS T0
LEFT JOIN [Table] AS T1 ON T0.ID = T1.ID AND T0.Code <> T1.Code
WHERE T1.ID IS NULL AND T0.ID = 'I'
```

Comment: This answer will return duplicate ids.

Comment: Thank you! The solution works as well but I didn't mention that the example table is a result of multiple joins already, would take longer time to run than the previous solution.

Answer (score 0):

It is highly likely that @GordonLinoff approach is fastest, but there are alternatives that have varying performance profiles depending on your data.

This first option assumes that:
- another table exists with all of the unique `id` values
- your table has an index on `(id, code)`

```
SELECT
   primary.id
FROM
   primary  -- the table with a unique list of your IDs
WHERE
   'I' = ALL (SELECT code FROM yourtable WHERE yourtable.id = primary.id)
```

This second option assumes that your table has two indexes:
- `(code, id)`  *(For finding IDs that do have an `'I'` code)*
- `(id, code)`  *(For finding if those IDs have any other codes)*

*(And is essentially similar to @ZacFaragher answer.)*

```
SELECT
   code_i.id
FROM
   your_table    code_i
WHERE
   code_i.code = 'I'
   AND NOT EXISTS (SELECT *
                     FROM yourtable
                    WHERE yourtable.id    = code_i.id
                      AND yourtable.code <> 'I'
                  )
```

It's often worth trying out different variations as different SQL Engines cope better/worse with correlated-sub-queries, etc.